How to handle frequently refreshed OIDC token in DVC repo
I have a DVC repo that is thought for storing data. I have a WebDAV remote. The authentication for the remote is done via oidc. I store the oidc token in the local.config file with

dvc remote modify --local hifis token oidc-token hifis_token

Now the problem is that the oidc token refreshes every 5 minutes. As far as I understand it this setting is fixed by the Client, which provides the storage. If I do dvc push this will sometimes take longer than 5 minutes and accordingly the token is refreshed but not updated in the local.config file and I get the error

unexpected error - received 401 (login failed): Client error ‘401 login failed’ for url …

Is there any solution to this? I guess I could have a script which always updated the local.config file in the backround but I don’t think this would solve the problem if the token is refreshed during a dvc operation like dvc push.
Thank you very much!
